# How did Queen feel about the Highlander film?

Tags: highlander

Queen songs played a big role in popularity of the Highlander movie.

Did Freddie Mercury or anyone else from Queen ever comment on the finished film and what they thought of it?

Comment: There's interviews about the album and film here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKTyBWDX4aQ  I haven't watched it though so don't know to what extent they talk about the film.

Comment: @Tim Not too much. However, it says they actually didn't want to do it (as they needed a break) and were convinced by a 20 minute cut of the film which they really liked. They also seemed to get script details and stuff to make songs for. So they were quite knit to the film rather than just having their songs tacked onto it, which *suggests* they liked what they were doing. But no, no clear statements and it also seems they had no actual control over *when* what song was played in the film, which means there could be room for creative differences.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - the most interesting bits were not film related directly, it was how they changed each others' songs, and the differences between soundtrack, UK record and US record. I didn't see 100% of the video yet though.

Comment: @DVK - does that video provide sufficient info to answer your question?  It's about the only thing I could find.

Comment: @Tim - I'm not sure I can accept that answer, but I if properly baked up from the quotes I am pretty sure it'd be an upvotable one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[From an interview with the director,  Russel Mulcahy](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2016/jul/05/highlander-how-we-made-sean-connery-christopher-lambert-russell-mulcahy-interview)...

> Queen had done a great score for Flash Gordon, so we gave them a 20-minute reel of different scenes and they went: “Wow!” We’d only expected them to do one song, but they wanted to write one each. Freddie Mercury did Princes of the Universe, Brian May did Who Wants to Live Forever, Roger Taylor did It’s a Kind of Magic.

It's also widely reported that Russel Mulcahy became good friends with Freddie after the film. I take this as tacit approval.

Comment: Hmm, that's still not much of a clear statement. The only relevant bit seems to be the supposition at the end, but I agree it's a reasonable supposition (though, that's also the part with a little less backing).

Comment: Congratulations, though, this is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4156/49).